# Internet Explorer installation in windows 10 enterprise

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

> Disclaimer: I don't know where to post this question. If it belongs in some other stack, then let me know.

I uninstalled internet explorer from windows 10 enterprise using following command and executed in cmd (taken from [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/some-images-and-content-not-displayed-as-well-as/1e400924-7662-4ee5-a2db-92f5e84438d3))

**FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*11.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /quiet /norestart"`**

Now, I am unable to reinstall IE.

I have tried multiple things, like tried installed IE using an offline installer. But I always find as installer for windows 7, not 10. And I get following error after executing the setup

> setup can't continue because a more recent version of internet explorer is installed

I have also tried [this](https://www.techbout.com/install-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-12490/), which essentially ask to go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn windows Features On and Off -> Check Internet Explorer and click Okay.

How can I install IE again without reinstalling windows. Thanks.

Comment: IE iis dead anyway it was replaced by edge. Why would you want to install dead software

Comment: Its a requirement by client (and employer) to support IE.

Comment: In order to solve this you will have to use DISM and point to an external source for the package (i.e. Windows 10 ISO) since the command remove the package from your installation.  Which is the reason you shouldn't have used that command.